# ListPointPlot3D with point color from a second list

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a 3D coordinates list while specifying each plot point a specific color taken from a color list.

Example:

```
XYZColorList = {{0.173534, 0.0893428, 0.0142678}, {0.470538, 0.355548,
 0.295788}, {0.475933, 0.360228, 0.300325}, {0.610688, 0.493085, 
0.443235}, {0.318969, 0.228664, 0.183534}, {0.315712, 0.227049, 
0.180459}, {0.0568048, 0.0291903, 0.00716188}, {0.0312732, 
0.0160486, 0.00492864}, {0.202566, 0.135997, 0.101508}, {0.205762,
 0.138551, 0.10393}};
XYZColors = Map[XYZColor, XYZColorList];
MunsellCoords = {{2.6711, -13.8497, 3.52451}, {-1.08771, -9.162, 
    6.51566}, {-1.09224, -9.1496, 6.55217}, {-0.973016, -7.894, 
    7.48612}, {-1.14851, -9.10948, 5.38254}, {-1.01615, -9.02445, 
    5.36571}, {2.87426, -9.10554, 1.95285}, {2.63322, -6.94949, 
    1.27857}, {-0.944056, -8.76566, 4.27216}, {-0.959735, -8.76519, 
    4.30807}};
ListPointPlot3D[MunsellCoords, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.033]]
```

So far, I've tried several examples on StackExchange where such questions are asked but I cannot figure it.

I tried a list of Directives for PlotStyle and a list of Style for the data yet.

I'm probably missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Using Mathematica 11.2 on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

```
ListPointPlot3D[MunsellCoords, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.033]] /. 
 Point[x_] :> Point[x, VertexColors -> XYZColors]
```

[image]

Comment: This method solved my issue. I still don't understand why I was getting errors (see comments in previous answer) using @kglr method though. Especially given that I've been using this method in previous plots without issues. So I'm obviously doing a little thing wrong and I just can't spot it.

Answer (score 4):

```
ListPointPlot3D[MapThread[Style, {MunsellCoords, XYZColors}], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.033]]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ListPointPlot3D[Thread[Style[MunsellCoords, XYZColors]], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.033]]
```

> same picture

```
ListPointPlot3D[List /@ MunsellCoords, 
 PlotStyle -> XYZColors, 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[0.033]]
```

> same picture

or

```
ListPointPlot3D[List /@ MunsellCoords, 
 PlotStyle -> Thread[Directive[XYZColors, PointSize[0.033]]]]
```

> same picture

Comment: I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I copied your example verbatim but I get the following errors:
 MapAt::partw: Part {10} of {{Directive[,PointSize[0.033]],Point[{{2.6711,-13.8497,3.52451},{-1.08771,-9.162,6.51566},{-1.09224,-9.1496,6.55217},{-0.973016,-7.894,7.48612},{-1.14851,-9.10948,5.38254},{-1.01615,-9.02445,5.36571},{2.87426,-9.10554,1.95285},{2.63322,-6.94949,1.27857},{-0.944056,-8.76566,4.27216},{-0.959735,-8.76519,4.30807}}]}} does not exist.
 MapAt::partw: Part {9} of MapAt[#1&,{{Directive[,PointSize[0.033]],Point[{{2.6711,-13.8497,3.52451},{,,,etc.

Comment: Seems I can't edit the comment after 5 minutes. The XYZColor square did not copied in my comment, So read "Directive[<color square>,PointSize[..."

Comment: I also get this error in the console: "MapAt is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive."

Comment: @YvesPoissant, it could be a version/os problem (the posted methods work without error in ver 11.3 (windows 10) for your posted lists `XYZColors` and `MunsellCoords`). In general, the methods should work for  lists `XYZColors` and `MunsellCoords` that have the same length.